# Filter source array based on the current filter and put its certain values to the ng-repeat item

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have an array called **schedules** that contains all flight schedules info. When user selects departure and arrival cities this array is being filtered by the selected cities and outputs flights in table. The table contains also columns for return flight data that initially source array **schedules** don't have. But there is a value **ret_flight_num**.

I want to load the return's flight data into the current row and still don't know how to implement this. Any suggestions?

```js
var app = angular.module('flight-schedule', []);

app.controller('SelectCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.flights = [
    {
      city: 'Ashgabat',
      destinations: ['Almaty', 'Amritsar']
    },
    {
      city: 'Amritsar',
      destinations: ['Ashgabat']
    },
    {
      city: 'Almaty',
      destinations: ['Ashgabat']
    }
  ];
  $scope.schedules = [{
    "city_from": "Ashgabat",
    "city_to": "Almaty",
    "aviacompany": "Türkmenhowaýollary DMG",
    "flight_num": "T5-717",
    "aircraft": "B-737-700",
    "dep_day": 5,
    "dep_time": "08-40",
    "land_time": "12-30",
    "ret_flight_num": "T5-718"
  }, {
    "city_from": "Ashgabat",
    "city_to": "Almaty",
    "aviacompany": "Türkmenhowaýollary DMG",
    "flight_num": "T5-715",
    "aircraft": "B-737-700",
    "dep_day": 7,
    "dep_time": "20-20",
    "land_time": "*00-10",
    "ret_flight_num": "T5-716"
  }, {
    "city_from": "Almaty",
    "city_to": "Ashgabat",
    "aviacompany": "Türkmenhowaýollary DMG",
    "flight_num": "T5-718",
    "aircraft": "B-737-700",
    "dep_day": 5,
    "dep_time": "14-00",
    "land_time": "16-00",
    "ret_flight_num": "T5-715"
  }, {
    "city_from": "Almaty",
    "city_to": "Ashgabat",
    "aviacompany": "Türkmenhowaýollary DMG",
    "flight_num": "T5-716",
    "aircraft": "B-737-700",
    "dep_day": 1,
    "dep_time": "01-40",
    "land_time": "03-40",
    "ret_flight_num": "T5-717"
  }, {
    "city_from": "Ashgabat",
    "city_to": "Amritsar",
    "aviacompany": "Türkmenhowaýollary DMG",
    "flight_num": "T5-551",
    "aircraft": "B-757-200",
    "dep_day": 1,
    "dep_time": "06-20",
    "land_time": "09-30",
    "ret_flight_num": "T5-552"
  }, {
    "city_from": "Ashgabat",
    "city_to": "Amritsar",
    "aviacompany": "Türkmenhowaýollary DMG",
    "flight_num": "T5-715",
    "aircraft": "B-737-700",
    "dep_day": 3,
    "dep_time": "03-25",
    "land_time": "06-35",
    "ret_flight_num": "T5-554"
  }, {
    "city_from": "Amritsar",
    "city_to": "Ashgabat",
    "aviacompany": "Türkmenhowaýollary DMG",
    "flight_num": "T5-718",
    "aircraft": "B-737-700",
    "dep_day": 2,
    "dep_time": "06-30",
    "land_time": "08-45",
    "ret_flight_num": "T5-553"
  }, {
    "city_from": "Amritsar",
    "city_to": "Ashgabat",
    "aviacompany": "Türkmenhowaýollary DMG",
    "flight_num": "T5-716",
    "aircraft": "B-737-700",
    "dep_day": 3,
    "dep_time": "08-05",
    "land_time": "10-20",
    "ret_flight_num": "T5-551"
  }];
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
}
td, th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.gray {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="flight-schedule">
  <h4>Flight schedules</h4>
  <div ng-controller="SelectCtrl">
    <form>
      <p>Departure city:
        <select ng-model="data.dep_city" ng-options="option as option.city for option in flights">
          <option value="">Select departure city</option>
        </select>
      </p>
      Selected deparure city: <strong>{{data.dep_city.city}}</strong>
      <p>Arrival city:
        <select ng-model="data.arr_city" ng-options="item for item in data.dep_city.destinations">
          <option value="">Select arrival city</option>
        </select>
      </p>
      Selected arrival city: <strong>{{data.arr_city}}</strong>
    </form>
    <p></p>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <th>Aviacompany</th>
        <th>Flight number</th>
        <th>Aircraft</th>
        <th>Departure day</th>
        <th>Departure time</th>
        <th>Landing time</th>
        <th class="gray">Return flight number</th>
        <th>Return flight departure day</th>
        <th>Return flight departure time</th>
        <th>Return flight landing time</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="flight in schedules | filter:{city_from: data.dep_city.city, city_to: data.arr_city}">
          <td>{{flight.aviacompany}}</td>
          <td>{{flight.flight_num}}</td>
          <td>{{flight.aircraft}}</td>
          <td>{{flight.dep_day}}</td>
          <td>{{flight.dep_time}}</td>
          <td>{{flight.land_time}}</td>
          <td class="gray">{{flight.ret_flight_num}}</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <caption>Flight schedules</caption>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

**[Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/ybqXmFA69JOyrXozEkDk?p=preview)**

Comment: `return's flight data` Which data is missing? From the server? Or from another array?

Comment: the return's flight data should be from the flight which flight_num equals current flight ret_flight_num value. Examle, flight from Ashgabat to Almaty with flight_num = "T5-717" has the return flight_num = "T5-718". Data should be from the same schedules array. I've editet the plunk a little. Is it clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`filter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) for this.

The logic is simple:

1. Find the return flight.
2. Get the data.
3. Display the data in the table

See the comments in the code (in the `filter` part) to better understanding..

```js
var app = angular.module('flight-schedule', []);

app.controller('SelectCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.flights = [
    {
      city: 'Ashgabat',
      destinations: ['Almaty', 'Amritsar']
    },
    {
      city: 'Amritsar',
      destinations: ['Ashgabat']
    },
    {
      city: 'Almaty',
      destinations: ['Ashgabat']
    }
  ];

  $scope.schedules = [{
    "city_from": "Ashgabat",
    "city_to": "Almaty",
    "aviacompany": "Türkmenhowaýollary DMG",
    "flight_num": "T5-717",
    "aircraft": "B-737-700",
    "dep_day": 5,
    "dep_time": "08-40",
    "land_time": "12-30",
    "ret_flight_num": "T5-718"
  }, {
    "city_from": "Ashgabat",
    "city_to": "Almaty",
    "aviacompany": "Türkmenhowaýollary DMG",
    "flight_num": "T5-715",
    "aircraft": "B-737-700",
    "dep_day": 7,
    "dep_time": "20-20",
    "land_time": "*00-10",
    "ret_flight_num": "T5-716"
  }, {
    "city_from": "Almaty",
    "city_to": "Ashgabat",
    "aviacompany": "Türkmenhowaýollary DMG",
    "flight_num": "T5-718",
    "aircraft": "B-737-700",
    "dep_day": 5,
    "dep_time": "14-00",
    "land_time": "16-00",
    "ret_flight_num": "T5-715"
  }, {
    "city_from": "Almaty",
    "city_to": "Ashgabat",
    "aviacompany": "Türkmenhowaýollary DMG",
    "flight_num": "T5-716",
    "aircraft": "B-737-700",
    "dep_day": 1,
    "dep_time": "01-40",
    "land_time": "03-40",
    "ret_flight_num": "T5-717"
  }, {
    "city_from": "Ashgabat",
    "city_to": "Amritsar",
    "aviacompany": "Türkmenhowaýollary DMG",
    "flight_num": "T5-551",
    "aircraft": "B-757-200",
    "dep_day": 1,
    "dep_time": "06-20",
    "land_time": "09-30",
    "ret_flight_num": "T5-552"
  }, {
    "city_from": "Ashgabat",
    "city_to": "Amritsar",
    "aviacompany": "Türkmenhowaýollary DMG",
    "flight_num": "T5-715",
    "aircraft": "B-737-700",
    "dep_day": 3,
    "dep_time": "03-25",
    "land_time": "06-35",
    "ret_flight_num": "T5-554"
  }, {
    "city_from": "Amritsar",
    "city_to": "Ashgabat",
    "aviacompany": "Türkmenhowaýollary DMG",
    "flight_num": "T5-718",
    "aircraft": "B-737-700",
    "dep_day": 2,
    "dep_time": "06-30",
    "land_time": "08-45",
    "ret_flight_num": "T5-553"
  }, {
    "city_from": "Amritsar",
    "city_to": "Ashgabat",
    "aviacompany": "Türkmenhowaýollary DMG",
    "flight_num": "T5-716",
    "aircraft": "B-737-700",
    "dep_day": 3,
    "dep_time": "08-05",
    "land_time": "10-20",
    "ret_flight_num": "T5-551"
  }];
});

// you call this filter using "flight.ret_flight_num | ret_flight_filter"
app.filter('ret_flight_filter', function() {
  return function(input /* flight.ret_flight_num */, 
                  prop /* the property you want to display */, 
                  collection /* schedules */, 
                  propToCompare /* flight.flight_num - by this parameter we can find the ret_flight_num */) {
    var founded = collection.filter(function(item) {
      return item[propToCompare] == input;
    });

    if (founded.length > 0) {
      return founded[0][prop];
    }
  }
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
}
td, th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.gray {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="flight-schedule">
  <h4>Flight schedules</h4>
  <div ng-controller="SelectCtrl">
    <form>
      <p>Departure city:
        <select ng-model="data.dep_city" ng-options="option as option.city for option in flights">
          <option value="">Select departure city</option>
        </select>
      </p>
      Selected deparure city: <strong>{{data.dep_city.city}}</strong>
      <p>Arrival city:
        <select ng-model="data.arr_city" ng-options="item for item in data.dep_city.destinations">
          <option value="">Select arrival city</option>
        </select>
      </p>
      Selected arrival city: <strong>{{data.arr_city}}</strong>
    </form>
    <p></p>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <th>Aviacompany</th>
        <th>Flight number</th>
        <th>Aircraft</th>
        <th>Departure day</th>
        <th>Departure time</th>
        <th>Landing time</th>
        <th class="gray">Return flight number</th>
        <th>Return flight departure day</th>
        <th>Return flight departure time</th>
        <th>Return flight landing time</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="flight in schedules | filter:{city_from: data.dep_city.city, city_to: data.arr_city}">
          <td>{{flight.aviacompany}}</td>
          <td>{{flight.flight_num}}</td>
          <td>{{flight.aircraft}}</td>
          <td>{{flight.dep_day}}</td>
          <td>{{flight.dep_time}}</td>
          <td>{{flight.land_time}}</td>
          <td class="gray">{{flight.ret_flight_num}}</td>
          <td>{{flight.ret_flight_num | ret_flight_filter: 'dep_day': schedules: 'flight_num'}}</td>
          <td>{{flight.ret_flight_num | ret_flight_filter: 'dep_time': schedules: 'flight_num'}}</td>
          <td>{{flight.ret_flight_num | ret_flight_filter: 'land_time': schedules: 'flight_num'}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <caption>Flight schedules</caption>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/3g6li87V0bErmvKuSgm8?p=preview).

**Was added:**

```
  $scope.schedules.forEach(function(item, i, arr){
    $scope.schedules.forEach(function(item2, i2, arr2){
       if(item.ret_flight_num == item2.flight_num && item.city_from == item2.city_to && item2.city_from == item.city_to){
            item.day = item2.dep_day;
            item.deptime = item2.dep_time;
            item.landtime = item2.land_time;
       }
     });
  });
```

**HTML:**

```
  <tr ng-repeat="flight in schedules | filter:{city_from: data.dep_city.city, city_to: data.arr_city}">
    <td>{{flight.aviacompany}}</td>
    <td>{{flight.flight_num}}</td>
    <td>{{flight.aircraft}}</td>
    <td>{{flight.dep_day}}</td>
    <td>{{flight.dep_time}}</td>
    <td>{{flight.land_time}}</td>
    <td class="gray">{{flight.ret_flight_num}}</td>

    <td>{{flight.day}}</td>
    <td>{{flight.deptime}}</td>
    <td>{{flight.landtime}}</td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: code is not working correctly. It's not showing proper return flights data. Example, Ashgabat - Almaty for flight "T5-717" return flight is "T5-718" which departs same day at 14:00 (look at schedules array)

Comment: Now is good! Thanks! But solution with filter is more maintainable and scalable for me!